# Можно ли сделать так, что бы при нажатии на определенную кнопку, бот оправил сообщение заданному пользователю

Tags: telegram-bot, бот

например это домашний бот, есть кнопка "купить хлеб", я нажимаю на эту кнопку, и мужу отправляется сообщение с текстом "купи хлеб", есть вторая кнопка, "хочу есть", муж нажимает ее и мне в личку приходит сообщение с текстом "приготовь покушать"

Answer (score 2):

```
wife = id_tlgrm
husband = id_tlgrm


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    start_kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    start_bread = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='купи хлеб', callback_data='bread')
    start_eat = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='хочу есть', callback_data='eat')
    start_kb.add(start_bread, start_eat)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'чего желаете?', reply_markup=start_kb)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'bread':
        if call.message.chat.id == husband:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'какой смысл просить себя?')
        else:
            bot.send_message(husband, 'Муж, сходи за хлебом')

    elif call.data == 'eat':
        if call.message.chat.id == wife:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'какой смысл просить себя?')
        else:
            bot.send_message(wife, 'Жена, приготовь покушать')
```

Comment: Не забываем что муж должен добавить бота

Comment: Точнее начать с ним диалог

Answer (score 0):

```
    bot.send_message(**12345678**, 'Муж, сходи за хлебом')
```

где **12345678** - user.id или chat.id пользователя

id можно получить к примеру через такое сообщение -

```
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.id)
```