# Как ответить на сообщение через тг бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Требуется реализовать следующее.
Нужно, чтобы пользователь, которому было отправлено сообщения по `chat_id = ''`, смог с помощью команды (reply) ответить через бота на данное сообщение

```
import config
import telebot



bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


chat_id = ''


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
message_text = 'Здравствуйте, '  + 
       message.from_user.first_name + "!" + 
'\nЯ Бот-отзовик.\nГотов принять ваш отзыв. 
\n/feedback - оставить отзыв'
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                           message_text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["feedback"])
def feedback(message):
   msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
   "Готов принять ваш отзыв: ")
# устанавливаем следующий шаг обработки 
     сообщения
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 
feedback_second) 
# передаем старое 
сообщение и функцию, в которой будем 
обрабатывать


def feedback_second(message):
   bot.forward_message(chat_id = chat_id, 
   from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, отзыв был отправлен ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Ну и куда должен идти ответ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109631/234134

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1114368/234134